# What is “t’en” in Je t’en prie?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

What part of speech is this and what does it actually mean?

How does this differ dramatically from the construction of the statement “je t’aime”?

Comment: Welcome to French Language. Have you read the [Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) before asking your question? And [this page in particular](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you please say what research you have done. Have you looked at the 102 [en](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en) tagged questions? Have you found anything helpful? Have you tried to find the phrase in a dictionary? (understanding the meaning helps finding what part of speech it is)....

Comment: Yes I’ve tried some of these things to an extent but am a very ripe beginner to French and so most of those tagged questions are over my head and I wouldn’t know how to look up an entire phrase.

Comment: Are [seeking answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/33171/seeking-answers) and [Jim](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/33170/jim) one and the same? They have different user numbers...  Anyway *je t'en prie* being a set phrase you can easily find it  in a dictionary, [e.g.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_t%27en_prie).

Comment: Nothing fundamentally new to add to the answers but contractions come and go as the flow of pronunciation dictates. Just consider both phrases in the hypothetical full form of "je te en prie" and "je te aime", the "en" belonging to the verb. So, for the context of your question, both are "je te *verb*". You can more clearly see this in the equivalent, polite form of "je vous en prie", where there's no contraction.

Answer (score 7):

*What part of speech is this and what does it actually mean?*

***T'en*** literally mean "you of it" or "you to do it". ***Je t'en prie*** is a set phrase so analysing its components can be pointless. Anyway, its literal meaning is "**I pray/beg you to** [do it]" and its intended one is "**You are welcome** [to do it]". It is built from ***Je** **te/vous** **prie*** which is equivalent to ***please***, including in English :

> Cassius. *Portia, art thou gone?*
> Brutus. *No more, I pray you.*
> Shakespeare: *Julius Caesar*, 1599

*How does this differ dramatically from the construction of the statement “je t’aime”?*

I don't think it does: "I pray you" and "I love you" aren't fundamentally different.

Comment: Excellent answer, bravo. 

Comment: Comment « **I beg you to** [do it] » s'est-il transformé en « **You are welcome** [to do it] » ? Ces deux significations diffèrent ! **Beg** se réfère à des besoins sérieux, urgents et stimulants. Mais **welcome** est bien plus décontracté et détendu. Par exemple, un employé d’un supermarché dirait : "**You are welcome to try** ces échantillons gratuits". Ce serait bizarre que l'agent dise : "**I beg you to** essayer ces échantillons gratuits." ???

Comment: Comme autre exemples, il est impossible d'échanger "*beg*" avec "*welcome*" ici — ["You are welcome to come join the preparation celebration. (. . .) you are welcome to invite your fellow soldiers to take food and drink with us."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Graveyard_Train/s1srIbpcTZcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22you+are+welcome+to%22&pg=PA192&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: ["you are welcome to question the credibility of the letter writers. (. . .) you are welcome to act as in #2 if there is good evidence."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thriving_Professor_The_A_Guide_To_A_Care/lvZtDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22you+are+welcome+to%22&pg=PA165&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Néanmoins, les expressions sont equivalents. Je dis "Je vous en prie" plusieurs fois pendant ma journée, et bien sûr je ne suis pas agenouillé chaque fois. Ce serait bizarre (en fait, seulement démodé) de dire I beg you to try my samples en Anglais, mais le répondeur n'a pas dit que to beg et you're welcome sont équivalents en Anglais. Iel a dit que je vous en prie et You are welcome (/My pleasure/ etc.) sont equivalent entre Anglais et Francais.

Comment: @user1147844 *I beg to differ* ;-) Une traduction littérale comme *beg* n'a pas besoin de fonctionner dans la langue cible contemporaine. Elle sert plus a faire comprendre le sens de chaque mot indépendamment des phrases où il apparaît. *Beg* est aujourd'hui plus proche de "supplier" alors que "prier" est plus proche de *pray*. *Beg* et *pray* ont quand même des sens proches.

Comment: Pouvez-vous développer plus de détails, s'il vous plaît ? Je reste toujours floue ! (Sans recourir à l’anglais) Même en français, la notion de mendier quelque chose diffère d’accueillir quelque chose.

Comment: @user1147844 Il ne s'agit pas de mendier mais de demander humblement et poliment. On peut remplacer sans en changer de le sens ***je vous en prie*** par ***je vous y invite***. Cette dernière expression est sémantiquement très proche de ***you are welcome** (to it)*.

Answer (score 4):

*Je t'en prie* is more or less a set expression, it corresponds to "go ahead" or "please do" to a question of the form "Mind if I X?" or "May I X?"

In this case, the full formulation is "Je te prie de X", with *en* being the pronominal form of the prepositional phrase *de X*. *T'en* is just the elided form of *te* + *en*. There are variants of the same construction: *je t'en supplie* or *je t'en conjure* for exemple, both of which being closer to "I beg of you".

Comment: What is meant by an eluded form?

Comment: yeah, that was a typo lol. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple uses for the phrase `Je t'en prie` and the meaning of `en` specifically might differ slightly between them. The two top answers right now cite one use each, both are valid uses.

First, unlike `aime`, `en` isn't a verbal form. `Je t'aime` is straightforwardly `Je te aime` > `I you love` > `I love you`. The `t'` merely refers to the listener. The fact that the proximity with `aime` has modified `te` into `t'` has nothing to do with semantics. It is simply due to pronunciation.

On the other hand, `en` refers to a third thing which is not either of the two people in the sentence. Typically it is some action that the second person has accomplished or is going to accomplish, or is invited to accomplish. A very common use case is this:

> Alice: *does something that warrants Bob to say thanks*

> Bob: "Merci"

> Alice: "Je t'en prie"

Here Alice praises Bob for the action of saying "Merci". This is a slightly formal tone, so you'll encounter "Je vous en prie" more often.

I should note that the phrase is never used to express an order or a request. So translating it to `I beg you to do it` is indeed wrong. It don't think that's even a correct literal translation. `prier` is not `to beg`, literally or otherwise. The correct literal translation would be `I pray you for this`, which has roughly the correct meaning.

Comment: "Beg" is probably a bit strong but it can indeed be used to express a request, including a fervent or insistent one. *Je m'assomme ici, dit Françoise, j'ai mal à la tête, je t'en prie, partons tout de suite.* - Proust, Les plaisirs et les jours.

Comment: Is it fair to say that “en” means it, and refers to “that which one has expressed thanks for, or which one has requested permission for”?

Comment: @Seekinganswers yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @guillaume31 thank you for helping this make sense to me!! 